# AWK - How to count all numbers in a file using functions

Tags: awk

I'm slightly confused because my pattern works if I don't use functions. On the other hand it doesn't.

Input file:

```
asd
111
22
3333
mike
44444
mas
```

My awk function: ( it always prints 1 instead of 4 )

```
function A(){
/[0-9]/ number++
print number
}

END{
A()
}
```

Pattern works if I use it outside the function but inside it always prints `1`, what's the problem??

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like `/[0-9]/` aren't usually used *inside* a block.  They are more commonly  used as

```
pattern { block }
```

If you want to test a regular expression against a string inside a function, use `match()`:

```
function A() {
    if (match($0, "[0-9]"))
        ++number
}

{
    A()
}

END {
    print number
}
```

This would count the number of line that contains at least one digit by calling `A()` for each line.  The function `A()` would match the `[0-9]` regular expression against the contents of the line and increase `number` by one if it matches.  The `END` block prints the resulting `number` at the end of the execution.

In place of `if (match($0, "[0-9]"))`, you could also use `if (/[0-9]/)`, but `match()` is more flexible.

This has the same effect as the `awk` program

```
/[0-9]/ { ++number }

END     { print number }
```

If you want to count the number of lines that contains only a positive integer (instead of lines that contains a digit somewhere), use `^[0-9]+$` as the regular expression instead.

The main point is that the function `A()` needs to be called for each line of input, and that the `number` variable's value should be printed in the `END` block.

---

The following *syntax* is accepted by the [POSIX `awk` grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html), but the program would however *not* count the number of lines containing a digit, but would count the number of lines.

```
function A() {
    /[0-9]/ ++number
}

{
    A()
}

END {
    print number
}
```

The statement `/[0-9]/ ++number` would evaluate to the character `0` or `1` (depending on whether the current line matches) concatenated with the result of `++number` as a string.

Since you call your `A()` function only in the `END` block, `number` would be incremented exactly once, and this is why you always get `1` as output.

Comment: `/[0-9]/ ++number` is `/[0-9]/` (0 or 1) concatenated with `++number`. There are cases where `/RE/` conflicts with `/` (division) when concatenation is involved (like in `a /foo/ b`), but that's not one of them.